# How do I compare values from different columns in 2 different csv filess?

Tags: python, python-2.7

1) How do I compare the values in column1 in csv1 with column 5 in csv2?

2) After comparing, how do I add the total sum of value in column 6 of the same ID in column 5?

[SAMPLE CONTENT OF CSV FILE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TadYg.png)

[SAMPLE CONTENT OF CSV FILE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Eyv.png)

E.g.

Column 5 Column 6

john $15050

john $36501

may $2000

tim $25

output:

Column 5 Column 6

john $51551

may $2000

tim $25

THIS ARE MY CODES SO FAR:

```
import csv

cname = open('file1.csv')
companyName = csv.reader(cname)

for comname in companyName:
    aname = open('file2.csv')
    awardName = csv.reader(aname)
    for awarname in awardName:
        if comname[0] == awarname[5]:
            print (awarname[5], awarname[6])
    aname.close()
cname.close()
```

OUTPUT

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '1134988')

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '376703.88')

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '910788')

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '504948')

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '40000')

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '6184')

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '1134988')

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '376703.88')

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '910788')

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '504948')

INTENDED OUTPUT

('9G ELEVATOR PTE. LTD.', '5901039.76')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum financial numbers I would rather use Decimal instead of float.
You will get better precision this way.

Here is my example solution, try it. Hope it helps:

```
import csv
from decimal import Decimal

cname = open('file1.csv')
companyName = list(csv.reader(cname))
cname.close()

aname = open('file2.csv')
awardName = list(csv.reader(aname))
aname.close()

for comname in list(set([cn[0] for cn in companyName])):
    print(
        comname,
        sum(
            [
                Decimal(item[6])
                for item in awardName if item[5] == comname
            ]
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hi robertu, thanks for the code, I needed to print the value in col 5 & 6 in csv 2 after comparing the value of col 5 of csv 2 with col 0 of csv 1. The code you have given works, but it ended up printing all the values in csv1 col 0 + the value of col 6 in csv 2 if col 0 csv1 == to col 5 csv2

Comment: Lines from file2.csv are stored in `awardName`. Columns from particular line are in variable `item`, so if you wish to print them, just print `item[col_number]`.

If you can include sample content from file1.csv and file2.csv that would help me understand your problem.

Comment: Hi robertu, I have included images of the contents of both the CSV file in the main post. The problem I am having is after comparing and verifying that the company name in column 5 of CSV file 2 exists in column 0 of CSV file 1 and print the company name in CSV file 2 with the total amount that company name has in column 6 without any duplicated company name. You would have a better idea after seeing the images.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the sample code above. Check if it works for you.

Comment: Hi robertu, the code work perfectly, however, the output still print out the company name in column 5 of csv file 2 even though it does not exists in coumn 0 of csv file 1

Comment: It should print only distinct names from column 0 of `file1.csv` as it iterates through `companyName` list.